# Frequent BSoD's With Varying Errors

Tags: windows-10, memory, drivers, crash, bsod

I have just recently finished building my computer and have had numerous problems with BSoD's. I have been getting errors about Memory_Corruption, Critical_Structure_Corruption, and IRQL_Not_Less_Or_Equal on Windows 10. Many websites have led me to believe that my RAM is at fault, but after testing with Memtest86 I found that was not the case. I attempted to use Windows "Verifier.exe," but my computer kept crashing every time I used it resulting in a Driver_Verifier_Detected_Error. It may be a faulty driver because I am using an old hard drive from a laptop, but I have had no luck in identifying any drivers that would cause a problem. I found the crash dump and sent it through WinDbg and found the problem was said to be caused by "Memory Corruption (One Bit)."
If there are any further steps I should take to fix this, any help is appreciated.

First Memory Management BSoD:

```
A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage
to your computer.

The problem seems to be caused by the following file: ntoskrnl.exe

MEMORY_MANAGEMENT

If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen,
restart your computer. If this screen appears again, follow
these steps:

Check to make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed.
If this is a new installation, ask your hardware or software manufacturer
for any Windows updates you might need.

If problems continue, disable or remove any newly installed hardware
or software. Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing.
If you need to use safe mode to remove or disable components, restart
your computer, press F8 to select Advanced Startup Options, and then
select Safe Mode.

Technical Information:

*** STOP: 0x0000001a (0x0000000000041792, 0xfffff6813d5675e8, 0x1000000000000000, 
0x0000000000000000)

*** ntoskrnl.exe - Address 0xfffff8024b74c480 base at 0xfffff8024b60a000 DateStamp 
0x56a849a9
```

First Driver Verifier BSoD:

```
A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage
to your computer.

The problem seems to be caused by the following file: ITEhidCIR.sys

DRIVER_VERIFIER_DETECTED_VIOLATION

If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen,
restart your computer. If this screen appears again, follow
these steps:

Check to make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed.
If this is a new installation, ask your hardware or software manufacturer
for any Windows updates you might need.

If problems continue, disable or remove any newly installed hardware
or software. Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing.
If you need to use safe mode to remove or disable components, restart
your computer, press F8 to select Advanced Startup Options, and then
select Safe Mode.

Technical Information:

*** STOP: 0x000000c4 (0x0000000000002004, 0xffffe001494dcd98, 0xfffff8018e1701f0, 
0xffffd0003d5db130)

*** ITEhidCIR.sys - Address 0xfffff8018e1701f0 base at 0xfffff8018e170000 DateStamp 
0x51e544ce
```

Edit: After running the crash dump from the Memory_Corruption error, WinDbg states for the default bucket ID "WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT" and the process name is InstallManager. Does this mean anything for the error? If it means anything, the hard drive that I am currently using is from an old laptop with much different hardware.

Comment: What are the full BSOD error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: If it's RAM, the only way to tell is to take all RAM out except 1, try to crash it, then swap it with the next stick.  This will generally tell you which RAM is bad, if one of the sticks are bad (could just need re-seated).  If you think it's a driver, the only way to tell is to check the crashdump in C:\Windows\minidump (google how to view windows crash dump).  That will give you more information about the error that caused the crash.  We will need the file name that caused the crash, and what happens if you try each RAM stick on it's own.

Comment: If you have more than 4GB of memory, memtest86 might not be able to test it all, especially if you're using an older version. I'd suggest doing what @dakre18 recommended: test each memory module separately. Your problem sounds *very* much like a RAM error.